# Android issues-ui with logs like some below

Tags: android

While my android ui interface is working, there is like a "terminal" on the upper right corner of the screen.
The words were

12.94/12.2/11.75
System_server
Surfaceflinger
Android.process.media
Mobile_log_d
Migration/1
Kworker/0:0
Logcat
Mmcqd\0

These are some of the things I see

is my phone being hacked?
What could be the problem? Why do these things appear?

Thanks. Hoping for you help..

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @rami. How can I upload the screen shot? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Add it as image or link to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I am sure you are seeing something like this (though you haven't provided any screenshots yourself)

It can only happen if the "**Show CPU Usage**" is turned on. You can see from the screenshot provided that for me this option is turned off.

**Your phone has not been hacked or compromised.** There is nothing to worry. Just turn it off and you are good to go.